# JSON date string parse error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I've got a large data model in a Rails application that I'm trying to make serializable and output to JSON. I defined the `#serializable_hash` method on the model and blacklisted a few attributes. My goal is to whitelist attributes on the controller layer to accept back that same structure and simply ignore values that I don't want "accessible".

One such attribute is giving me trouble when I `PUT update` with the aforementioned JSON. I get an error while parsing request parameters:

```
SyntaxError (/Users/brad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@project-rails32/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:261: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting $end
...02933", "software_date"=>"09/05/14", "software_version"=>"10...
...                               ^):
# stack trace...
```

As far as Rails is concerned, this is just a string right? Why is it expecting an end of input here? For the record, taking this attribute out before submitting my request results in a successful update, so I'm sure this is what's causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I'm the unluckiest guy in the world.

Familiarize yourself with Ruby's [%Q()](http://simpleror.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/q-q-w-w-x-r-s/) method, and you'll understand where I'm at.

Under my very *very* specific case, when Rails is parsing params for a request:

1. in JSON format
2. which has a key mapping to an Array
3. and *any* value under that Array contains a '/'

the parse will fail. Why?

My version of Rails (3.2.13) uses the AwesomePrint library version 0.3.2 when parsing out parameters for the `params` hash. [The #grep method](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print/blob/0.3.2/lib/ap/core_ext/array.rb#L59) for that version of the gem evaluates matches using:

```
%Q/#{match}/
```

Simply because the specified delimiter is a '/', the evaluation fails and parsing crashes. DO NOT LET THIS HAPPEN TO YOU.